# c++11 boost linking erors?

Tags: c++11, boost, linker

I am trying to run some C++11 code (not mine), with four .cpp files:datainfo, pcim,  demo,  traj and a Makefile. The files compile with no errors, but then

g++  -lboost_serialization -lpthread -o demo datainfo.o pcim.o demo.o traj.o

gives a multiple errors that look like this:
datainfo.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, datainfo>::load_object_ptr(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*&, unsigned int) const':
datainfo.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost7archive6detail19pointer_iserializerINS0_12xml_iarchiveE8datainfoE15load_object_ptrERNS1_14basic_iarchiveERPvj[_ZNK5boost7archive6detail19pointer_iserializerINS0_12xml_iarchiveE8datainfoE15load_object_ptrERNS1_14basic_iarchiveERPvj]+0xa3): undefined reference to`boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::next_object_pointer(void*)'

The boost lib files are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and the .hpp files are in /usr/include/boost $. I am running on a server with Mint 17.2 rafaela. I am not very familiar with C++, but I am guessing it might be a linking issue?.